# Ошибка при передаче client session aiohttp

Tags: python, asyncio, aiohttp

Пытаюсь передать сессию между функциями в python, но происходит ошибка:

```
Exception has occurred: RuntimeError
Session is closed
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\Desktop\connserv.py", line 31, in edit_db
    async with client.get(url=url, params=params) as resp:
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\Desktop\connserv.py", line 43, in <module>
    asyncio.run(edit_db())
```

Код который я использую:

```
from aiohttp import ClientSession, client
import asyncio

async def send_request():
    url = ''
    params = {
        'email': "",
        "pass": "",
        "authorization": "true"
    } 

    async with ClientSession() as client:
        async with client.post(url, params=params) as resp:
            return client


async def edit_db():
    client = await send_request()
    
    url = ''
    params = {
        "ID": "248098",
        "data[name]": "Statistics [ Global Timezones Bot ]",
        "data[text]": f"""reefe""",
        "action": "edit_record",
        "data[category_ID]": "82627"
    }

    async with client.post(url=url, params=params) as resp:
        print(resp.text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(edit_db())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После

```
return client
```

контекст менеджер with закрывается.

```
client = ClientSession()
....
return client
```